# How to fix the balloon position in R-amChart

Tags: r, amcharts

Let say I have below amChart in R

```
library(pipeR)
library(rAmCharts)
library(purrr)
set.seed(1)
Dat = data.frame(x = paste(as.character(-10:10), "%", sep = ""), y = -10:10, z=rnorm(21))

balloonFunction <- htmlwidgets::JS(
    'function(item) {',
    'if (item.category!="0%") { return \'X: \' + item.category + 
                               \'<br>Y: \' + item.values.value +
                               \'<br>Z: \' + item.dataContext[\'z\'];}',
    '}')

p <- amSerialChart(categoryField = "x", precision = 2) %>%
  setDataProvider(dataProvider = Dat, keepNA = TRUE) %>%
  addGraph(valueField = "y", lineColor = "gray", fillAlphas=0.5, 
           bullet="round", lineThickness=4) %>%
  setChartCursor() %>%
  setBalloon(cornerRadius=10, color="white", fillColor="red", textAlign="left")
p@graphs[[1]]$balloonFunction <- balloonFunction
p@valueAxes <- list(list(title='y-axis name', position='left', axisAlpha=0.5))
p@categoryAxis <- list(title='x-axis name', axisAlpha=0.5)
p
```

Now, I want to fix the Balloon position on the chart. I want the Balloon should be vertically aligned at centered and horizontally aligned at left.

Any pointer how to achieve this in the R implementation of amChart, would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

**Implementation based on  xorspark's feedback**

Below is a Shiny app to demonstrate how the position of balloon can be fixed.

**ui.R**

```
library(rAmCharts)
library(pipeR)
library(purrr)


 fluidPage(
    tagList(tags$head(includeCSS("CSS.css"))),
  selectInput("Dummy", "Some Dummy number:",c(1,2,3)),

  div(id = "balloon"),

  div(amChartsOutput("Plot", height = "400px"))
)
```

**server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(1)

    balloonFunction <- htmlwidgets::JS(
          "function(item) {",
          "document.getElementById('balloon').innerHTML = item.dataContext.z;",

           "}")

    labFunx <- htmlwidgets::JS(
          'function(value) {',
          'return value+\'%\';',    
          '}')

    dat = structure(list(x = c(-100, -99.61, -99.22, -98.83, -98.43, -98.04, 
-97.65, -97.26, -96.87, -96.48, -96.09, -95.69, -95.3, -94.91, 
-94.52, -94.13, -93.74, -93.35, -92.95, -92.56, -92.17, -91.78, 
-91.39, -90, -90.61, -90.22, -89.82, -89.43, -89.04, -88.65), 
    y = c(1.7597036882208e-16, 3.74523809420545e-16, 6.79924138728896e-16, 
    5.49147548890779e-16, 2.8444302872708e-16, 2.01730936037434e-16, 
    4.72623693209037e-16, 5.25606872427607e-16, 5.75755789341732e-19, 
    2.74318552000638e-17, 7.41872388571549e-17, 1.16379243552747e-16, 
    1.30330176931005e-17, 1.44493324181405e-16, 1.48200512266161e-16, 
    2.12152823477696e-16, 1.23512766683157e-16, 1.32574841143743e-16, 
    4.4989064700399e-17, 1.34533164086192e-16, 1.9006081627268e-16, 
    2.39080196757097e-16, 1.19793582322272e-16, 9.50635502478515e-17, 
    8.85078754774532e-17, 4.07507372548731e-17, 4.87962996842999e-17, 
    0, 0, 0), z = c("Balloon -100", "Balloon -99.61", "Balloon -99.22", 
    "Balloon -98.83", "Balloon -98.43", "Balloon -98.04", "Balloon -97.65", 
    "Balloon -97.26", "Balloon -96.87", "Balloon -96.48", "Balloon -96.09", 
    "Balloon -95.69", "Balloon -95.3", "Balloon -94.91", "Balloon -94.52", 
    "Balloon -94.13", "Balloon -93.74", "Balloon -93.35", "Balloon -92.95", 
    "Balloon -92.56", "Balloon -92.17", "Balloon -91.78", "Balloon -91.39", 
    "Balloon -90", "Balloon -90.61", "Balloon -90.22", "Balloon -89.82", 
    "Balloon -89.43", "Balloon -89.04", "Balloon -88.65")), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")




    dat <- dat[order(dat$x),]
    nr <- nrow(dat)
    last.row <- dat[nr,]
    last.row$y <- 0
    dat <- rbind(dat, last.row)
    p <- amXYChart(x=dat$x, y=dat$y) %>%
          setDataProvider(dataProvider = dat, keepNA = TRUE) %>%
          addGraph(xField = "x", yField = "y", lineColor = "gray", fillAlphas=0.5,
                   bullet="round", lineThickness=2, bulletColor="transparent") %>%
          setChartCursor() %>%
          setBalloon(cornerRadius=10, color="black", textAlign="left", maxWidth = 1300) 
    p@graphs[[1]]$balloonFunction <- balloonFunction
    p@valueAxes <- list(list(title='x-axis name', position='bottom',axisAlpha=0.5,
                             labelFunction=labFunx),
                        list(title='y-axis name', position='left',axisAlpha=0.5))
    output$Plot = renderAmCharts(p)

}
```

**CSS**

```
#balloon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 70px;
  left: 30px;
  background: #FFA500;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

*Although, my original question is now resolved, what I observed is, I still see balloon values even if I remove my Mouse pointer out of chart container. This I do not want. I should only see balloon value only if I hover my Mouse ove the chart*

Any idea how to resolve this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Marco, I expect the balloon will be shown in a fixed place in the chart container, i.e. it's placement will not move when I hover over the chart. That fixed place for balloon will be on the left edge of chart container and in vertically middle position

Comment: That's definitely not feasible with the base AmCharts API as balloons will always be next to a bullet. I'm not well versed in R at the moment but you might find [this example useful](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/displaying-rollover-information-fixed-position-div/) if you're able to incorporate external HTML and CSS into your setup to accommodate the custom balloon functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Hi  xorspark, based on your feedback I have created a Shiny app. I edited my original post to present that Shiny app. One further question though: There should not be any balloon value if I do not hover my Mouse over the chart container. Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the solution given [here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/displaying-rollover-information-fixed-position-div/) can work only with `amCharts` time series plots (`type = "serial"`).
A solution that works with `amCharts` scatter plots (`type = "xy"`) is given [here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/detecting-at-what-value-mouse-pointer-is/).
Below you can find some ideas that could help you.

```
library(rAmCharts)
library(purrr)
library(shiny)       
dat <- structure(list(x = c(-100, -99.61, -99.22, -98.83, -98.43, -98.04, 
-97.65, -97.26, -96.87, -96.48, -96.09, -95.69, -95.3, -94.91, 
-94.52, -94.13, -93.74, -93.35, -92.95, -92.56, -92.17, -91.78, 
-91.39, -90, -90.61, -90.22, -89.82, -89.43, -89.04, -88.65), 
    y = c(1.7597036882208e-16, 3.74523809420545e-16, 6.79924138728896e-16, 
    5.49147548890779e-16, 2.8444302872708e-16, 2.01730936037434e-16, 
    4.72623693209037e-16, 5.25606872427607e-16, 5.75755789341732e-19, 
    2.74318552000638e-17, 7.41872388571549e-17, 1.16379243552747e-16, 
    1.30330176931005e-17, 1.44493324181405e-16, 1.48200512266161e-16, 
    2.12152823477696e-16, 1.23512766683157e-16, 1.32574841143743e-16, 
    4.4989064700399e-17, 1.34533164086192e-16, 1.9006081627268e-16, 
    2.39080196757097e-16, 1.19793582322272e-16, 9.50635502478515e-17, 
    8.85078754774532e-17, 4.07507372548731e-17, 4.87962996842999e-17, 
    0, 0, 0), z = c("Balloon -100", "Balloon -99.61", "Balloon -99.22", 
    "Balloon -98.83", "Balloon -98.43", "Balloon -98.04", "Balloon -97.65", 
    "Balloon -97.26", "Balloon -96.87", "Balloon -96.48", "Balloon -96.09", 
    "Balloon -95.69", "Balloon -95.3", "Balloon -94.91", "Balloon -94.52", 
    "Balloon -94.13", "Balloon -93.74", "Balloon -93.35", "Balloon -92.95", 
    "Balloon -92.56", "Balloon -92.17", "Balloon -91.78", "Balloon -91.39", 
    "Balloon -90", "Balloon -90.61", "Balloon -90.22", "Balloon -89.82", 
    "Balloon -89.43", "Balloon -89.04", "Balloon -88.65")), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
    tagList(tags$head(includeCSS("CSS.css"))),
    selectInput("Dummy", "Some Dummy number:",c(1,2,3)),
    div(id = "balloon"),
    div(amChartsOutput("Plot", height = "800px", width="1600px"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    balloonFunction <- htmlwidgets::JS(
          'function(item) {',
          'if (item.dataContext[\'x\']!=0) { 
               return \'X: \' + item.dataContext.x + 
                  \'<br>Y: \' + item.dataContext.y +  
                  \'<br>Z: \' + item.dataContext.z;}',
           '}')

    labFunx <- htmlwidgets::JS(
          'function(value) {',
          'return value+\'%\';',    
          '}')

    # Add two points to the series in order to plot correctly the 
    # area below the line
    dat <- dat[order(dat$x),]
    nr <- nrow(dat)
    first.row <- dat[1,]
    first.row$y <- 0
    last.row <- dat[nr,]
    last.row$y <- 0
    dat <- rbind(first.row, dat, last.row)

    # Define Javascript function for plotting x-y values 
    # inside the fixed-position balloon
    prt.balloon <- paste(
      "function(event) {",
      "var xValue = AmCharts.charts[0].graphs[0].xAxis.coordinateToValue(event.x);",
      "var yValue = AmCharts.charts[0].graphs[0].yAxis.coordinateToValue(event.y);",
      "document.getElementById('balloon').innerHTML='x:' + xValue + '<br>y:' + yValue;",
      "}", sep="\n")

    # Create chart cursor
    chrCur <- chartCursor(cursorPosition="mouse") %>% 
              addListener(name="moved", expression=prt.balloon)

    p <- new("AmChart", type="xy", chartCursor=chrCur)  %>% 
         setDataProvider(dataProvider=dat, keepNA=TRUE) %>%
         addGraph(balloonText="", balloonFunction=balloonFunction, 
           xField = "x", yField = "y", lineColor = "gray", fillAlphas=0.5,
           bullet="round", lineThickness=2, bulletColor="transparent") 
    p@valueAxes <- list(list(title='x-axis name', position='bottom',axisAlpha=0.5,
                             labelFunction=labFunx),
                        list(title='y-axis name', position='left',axisAlpha=0.5))

   output$Plot = renderAmCharts(p)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**CSS.css**

```
#balloon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 1200px;
  background: #FFA500;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marco for your solution. However I still didnt get any solution on when I remove my Mouse pointer outside of Chart window, the last balloon should go-off. In your chart it still remains on the screen

Comment: Hi Marco - I recently posted a new topic on rAmCharts on how to implement a clustered bar chart in - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399259/clustered-stacked-column-chart-using-ramcharts-package. So far I failed to solicit any reply, would you please help me out?